# Why does VSCode display closing "fi"'s in a different font?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Consider line 197, the "fi" is definitely in a different font than the corresponding "if". I have no idea why that's the case, but it doesn't seem to help switching font.

I'm currently using the Menlo font on macOS.

[image: screenshot showing the problem]

Comment: Related: [Ligatures Limited extension for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kshetline.ligatures-limited)

Comment: go to settings and disable ligatures